# PySpark Logging

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, log4j, stackdriver

I'm trying to view the spark logs in GCP stack driver. Below is the screenshot of the stack driver.

[image]

As per the above screenshot Spark INFO's are mapping to ERROR in stack driver. Not sure why?

I'm using log4j for spark custom logging. Below are the log properties.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p    %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty=INFO
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
```

Any suggestions to map spark log(INFO) to stack driver log(INFO)?

Answer (score 0):

Stackdriver reads some messages as the severity, in this case you have

```
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
```

Try add a "Severity" field to your logs with the proper value and, this way, Stackdriver would read it as you specify, check the values [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogSeverity). Also you can check the correct format at the beginning of the page.